# Using parent() three times, is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next(".results-table").css("display", "block");
```

Basically, after clicking a link inside of a table, the following results table will show, the problem is that this link is inside a td, which is inside a tr, which of course is inside a table, hence the repeated parent selector.

Is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing? I've not got lots of experience with jQuery unfortunately.

Comment: depending on your DOM, .parents("yourSelector") might work better

Comment: Could you add an example block of your table showing any classes or id's on elements? That would be more beneficial than explaining how your elements are layed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(this).parents("table").next(".results-table").css("display", "block");
```

or

```
jQuery(this).closest("table").next(".results-table").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any benefits over closest over parents and vice versa?

Comment: There's a 2-column comparison between `.closest` and `.parents()` in the page Alex linked. In short for your case, `.closest()` will stop when it finds the first closest parent table, while `.parents()` crawls up all the way to document level.

Comment: parents finds none, one or multiple elements while closest will find none or one element and includes the root element.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `jQuery(this).closest("table")` http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(this).closest('table').css("display", "block");
```

or even

```
jQuery(this).closest('.results_table').css("display", "block");
```

dependent on your desired result and your HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents(":eq(3)")
```

This could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Or.. you could possibly make use of event delegation, such as .on() instead of .click(). Then, you can simply use e.delegateTarget.

For example,

```
$(parent).on("click", link, function(e) {
    jQuery(e.delegateTarget).next(".results-table").css("display", "block");
});
```